# How to Find text and replace using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Im trying to find a solution to search for a text string "Tony" contained in the DOM and replace it with a text String "Tiger".

Anyone have any insight or ideas of how to do so? Im guessing it will take an each statement coupled with a replace function and possibly contains?

Thanks
Jake

Comment: More details, please. Do you have any idea of _where_ in the DOM it might be? Do you want to replace _every_ occurrence of `Tony` with `Tiger` no matter where it occurs?

Comment: do you the html container for that?? or its straight replace all

Comment: Yes, I want to replace every occurence of "Tony" with "Tiger" - where ever in the DOM it lies - must probably within the .container element.

Comment: You should probably clarify, but I assume you only want to replace **text nodes** that contain the string "Tony"... i.e. don't replace if it appears in an attribute

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this to search all children of the body element and replace the text...

```
$('body').children().each(function(){$(this).text( $(this).text().replace('Tony','Tiger') )});
```

It uses jQuery. It also should only alter the textual content of elements and none of the HTML formatting...

You can also use this method which uses a RegExp and will get all nested elements:

```
 $('body').html( $('body').html().replace(/Tony/gi,'tiger') );
```

Comment: This won't work because `children()` doesn't recursively search through the DOM - it only gives you the immediate children.

Comment: Its not working on my page: http://www.laithwaiteswine.com $('.container').children().each(function(){$(this).text( $(this).text().replace('Laithwaites','Tiger') )});  - It is removing all the DOM or breaking it.

Comment: @jrutter: Not sure why that is happening to you without seeing your code. However, I have upated my solution with an alternate one using a RegExp approach ---> $('body').html( $('body').html().replace(/Tony/gi,'tiger') );

Comment: I tested it and it worked well even if items are nested multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Page wide, you can use something like this:

```
var $body = $('body');
var html = $body.html();
var newHtml = html.replace('Tony', 'Tiger');
$body.html(newHtml);
```

Or, if you have a more specific container, use jQuery to select that child container and do the same thing.

Either way, it is sort of a shotgun approach.  It will change the string in both visible text and html element attributes.  A more detailed approach might be needed if the string needed to be ignored in certain locations.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to couple this with a server-side solution? You could wrap every occurence of the word server side with a special class, like `<span class="replaceme">texttoreplace</span>`.

Running a javascript replace on the resulting classes only should speed things up.

Comment: If this was a possibility, why wouldn't he replace the string on the server side to begin with? Adding unnecessary dom elements seems excessive