# jQuery text placeholders (select by text?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if jQuery (or maybe a plugin of jQuery) has the ability to select a text in the page so I could replace it. Similar to what is done in AngularJS with {{myExpression}} - what I would like to do is select {{myExpression}} and replace it with something else using jQuery.

Yes - I know I can have an empty span with an id and change it's inner text - that's not what I need.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, jQuery, in fact _JavaScript_ can do it.

Comment: Why don't you use AngularJS then?

Comment: @ShijuKBabu can't use AngularJS (although I really wanted to) since this project I'm working on should support older browsers (I'm talking as old as IE6 - YES!!! I know!!!!) and Angular is not supported under 8 I think.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variation of the `:contains` selector.

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

**Example given:**

```
<div>John Resig</div>
<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>

<script>
$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
</script>
```

**Edit:** Upon further research, this appears to be a duplicate of these questions:

- [How to Find text and replace using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455606/how-to-find-text-and-replace-using-jquery)
- [How do I do string replace in JavaScript to convert ‘9.61’ to ‘9:61’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145988/how-do-i-do-string-replace-in-javascript-to-convert-9-61-to-961)
- [jquery find and replace text, without element id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349138/jquery-find-and-replace-text-without-element-id)
- [Jquery: Find Text and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146648/jquery-find-text-and-replace)
- [jQuery find and replace string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115152/jquery-find-and-replace-string)
- [jQuery - Find and replace text, after body was loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349446/jquery-find-and-replace-text-after-body-was-loaded)
- [Find and replace text with jquery, only text no child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205296/find-and-replace-text-with-jquery-only-text-no-child-elements)

Answer (score 1):

$('*:contains("myMessage")') returns a jQuery object that contains matched elements